# 'rvm' is currently not installed. (Works on one terminal but not the other)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I just went about the process of installing ruby and rvm.

This is all very confusing, whilst RVM is working on the terminal I installed it on, it is not working on any other and I am getting the following error:

`The program 'rvm' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm`

Could there be an issue with my paths, or another version of ruby or RVM that is causing this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "terminal"? I assume in each case you're logged in as the same user?

Comment: Maybe you need to update your bash profile? source ~/.bashrc or source ~/.bash_profile ?

Comment: source ./bashrc worked a charm, can you explain what its doing (still a bit of a linux amateur here). Thanks!

Comment: When you install `rvm` it updates your profile. So unless you re-execute it, your environment won't be set up properly for `rvm`.

Comment: @meub is there a way you can add this as the answer to I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying sourcing your bash profile.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Or

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Also: `. ~/.bash_profile` works.

This runs your bash profile in your current context (your current shell process) and sets the environment variables so they remain in this context. This is different from executing the .bash_profile like this: `./.bash_profile` which will create a new shell, execute the commands there and thus not affect your current shell process.

Answer (score 1):

If you just finished to install it, to have access in all terminals you need to logout and login again, in order to load the new environmental variables on your `.bashrc` or `.bashprofile`